# Compare two lists from sql in python and show result using pandas.io

Tags: python, sql, list, pandas

I'm having a question on python. I'm trying to compare two dataframes and check which elements are different and insert them into another dataframe. So here are my dataframes. df1:

```
PN      Stock        WHS      Cost
1111     1           VLN       0.2
1111     2           VLN       0.2
1115     1           KNS       0.5
```

df2:

```
    PN      Stock        WHS      Cost    Time
   1111        1         VLN       0.2     15:00
   1111        3         VLN       0.2     16:00
```

So the idea is to add to df1 the data from df2 that is not yet in df1; line 2 in df2 does not exist in df1 so I want to insert it. 
How should i write code to find not existing line so that I could insert it?
I have tried:

```
   for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        if df2[(df2['PN']==row['PN']) & (df2['Stock'] ==row['Stock']) & (df2['Whs'] = row['Whs']) & (df2['Cost']==row['Cost'])].empty
              print row['PN']
```

To check which rows to update but i get basically all rows printed, not the ones that do not match. How can I solve this please? Is it possible to use somehow 'IN' function, comparing each df1 line with whole df2???

Comment: `line 2 in List2 does not exist in List1`?? It does. Only the `Time` columns does not exist...

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense can you post desired output, also you state line2 in your 2nd df does not exist but it does

Comment: sorry guys, updated question, now line 2 in list2 does not exist in list1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to perform an outer [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [29]:

df.merge(df1, how='outer')
Out[29]:
     PN  Stock  WHS  Cost   Time
0  1111      1  VLN   0.2  15:00
1  1111      2  VLN   0.2    NaN
2  1115      1  KNS   0.5    NaN
3  1111      3  VLN   0.2  16:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use outer join to achieve this result

```
    pd.concat([df1,df2],join='outer')
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html for more options about how you want to deal with indexes etc..